GitHub Actions, Laravel 11 Sail problems
Trying to create GitHub Actions to deploy a Laravel 11 app running Laravel Sail. Almost all tasks run good, but at this point, an error occurs and I can't find the solution.
Have created the docker image and pushed to DockerHub ok.
The app runs goos at my local machine.
Here is the YAML file at the .gitignore/workflows directory:
name: CI/CD Pipeline

on:
 push:
 branches:
  - main

jobs:
 build:
 runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Setup PHP
    uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
    with:
      php-version: '8.2'

  - name: Install Composer dependencies
    run: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

  - name: List files in runtimes directory
    run: ls -la ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.3

  - name: Set up Docker Buildx
    uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

  - name: Login to Docker Hub
    uses: docker/login-action@v2
    with:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

  - name: Build and push Docker image
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
    with:
      context: .
      file: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.3/Dockerfile
      push: true
      tags: marcellopato/webroker:latest
      build-args: |
        WWWGROUP=1000

deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
needs: build

steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Deploy to EC2
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.6
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.EC2_USER }}
      key: ${{ secrets.EC2_KEY }}
      port: ${{ secrets.EC2_PORT }}
      script: |
        docker pull marcellopato/webroker:latest
        docker stop webroker || true
        docker rm webroker || true
        docker run -d --name webroker -p 80:8000 marcellopato/webroker:latest

And down here we can see the error while running tha Action:
  59 |     COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
  60 |     COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
  61 | >>> COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
  62 |     RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container
  63 |     
  --------------------
 ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of 
 ref v887cgr95ybaz3q64gl0c2lo9::vwav0i7uupd474mws0jlq4xv9: "/php.ini": not found
 Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref v887cgr95ybaz3q64gl0c2lo9::vwav0i7uupd474mws0jlq4xv9: "/php.ini": not found

The rest of the docker files are all from Laravel Sail and still originals.
Anyone?

Does php.ini exist alongside supervisord.conf?
If not, you might want to run artisan sail:publish (or you can copy it out of the vendor directory).

Are you using Sail in production?
Sail is not for production use.
Development only.
If you don't know how to deploy Laravel to production, use Laravel Forge.

Sure man! What a mess! Thanks
